# feof(file) does not terminate loop in cLion for macOS

Tags: macos, while-loop, clion, feof

Why does this code result in infinite loop on cLion, while on opening the project on Xcode it works normally and terminates on finding on EOF?

```
       while (!feof(file)) {
        fscanf(file, "%d", &number);
        printf("%d\t",number);
    }
```

Comment: Hard to say when your code is incomplete and you give no indication what options you compiled it with...

Comment: It is just a trial in the main function to read integers separated by tabs from a .txt file.

Comment: Questions are supposed to include a **minimum, complete example** of code that can be compiled and tested. The compiler, compile/link options you use, and the header files you include all make a difference.